# Is there an equivalent to iOS' identifierForVendor for android?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

In iOS 6, [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor provides a unique ID across all the apps from a single vendor.

Is there any way to do the same thing in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Android Id:
[Generating Device-Specific Serial Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464881/generating-device-specific-serial-number/13839341#13839341)

Note that Android is designed so you can't automatically get a full device id. Android even [modified a pre-existing part of linux](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#userid) that would have made this possible.

Even better than Android id: your app can request the AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS permission. Then you know the user's Google id. This will be common across all apps and phones the user uses.

Comment: Neither of those IDs is persistently specific to a device, but the ANDROID_ID is the best option.  I like the way iOS has implemented the identifierForVendor as this is a very common use case for developers, and it doesn't identify the device, only the vendor-device combo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more recent official option for this purpose, which is called the "App Set ID" SDK:

> For example, suppose you publish two apps under your Google Play developer account and both apps are installed on the same device through the Google Play store. The apps share the same app set ID on that device. The ID is the same even if the apps are signed by different keys.

```kotlin
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-appset:16.0.2")
```

```kotlin
val client = AppSet.getClient(applicationContext) as AppSetIdClient
val task: Task<AppSetIdInfo> = client.appSetIdInfo as Task<AppSetIdInfo>

task.addOnSuccessListener({
    // Determine current scope of app set ID.
    val scope: Int = it.scope

    // Read app set ID value, which uses version 4 of the
    // universally unique identifier (UUID) format.
    val id: String = it.id
})
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/app-set-id