# Android Device ID change while device factory reset

Tags: android, unique, reset, imei, deviceid

I need a Unique ID or Number all time, If device formate or flash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent to iOS' identifierForVendor for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657977/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ios-identifierforvendor-for-android)

Comment: Nothing can help you.! after factory reset.

Comment: @J.K Is there any possibility to get unique values of device ID or IMEI or any ... after flash OR factory reset ?

Answer (score 0):

For Android development, you can use a universally unique identifier (UUID) to generate a unique ID that can persist even if the device is formatted or flashed.

```
import java.util.UUID;

UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String uniqueId = uuid.toString();
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP wants an identifier that survives factory reset of a device.

Comment: If device factory reset UUID change every time. My requirement is no need to change even factory reset or flash device.

Comment: Then You may use IMEI. However, I should clarify that the permanent identification that you are looking for is not currently available on Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mac address of the device

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).